# Django cant be reached via parameterized url

Tags: python, django, url, browser, http-status-code-404

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm currently learning how to use the library Django combined with Python. However, I've ran into some issues which are somehow strange. My situation is the following. I have a project called "animals" which is the base of the Django application. My app is called "polls". Then I've defined the following views.

**polls/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def animals(request, animal_id):
    return HttpResponse("%s" % animal_id)

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

So far, so good. Unfortunatly I can't say the same about the urlpatterns.

**polls/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    # Redirects to localhost:8000/polls/<animal_id>
    path('<int:animal_id>/',views.animals,name='animals')    
]
```

Whenever I want to navigate to the url "localhost:8000/polls/10/" Django reminds me of the fact, that the url is not accepted by the application and a 404 Error is thrown inside my browser. Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to resolve the problem by fixing a rather trivial error. While the *polls/urls.py* was alright, the problem lay inside the *animals/urls.py* file. This file looked like this:

**animals/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls',include('polls.urls')),
]
```

As one can see, the "polls" path is not finished with a "/" sign. This indicates to Django that my desired route would be *localhost:8000/polls* where  is any integer I add to the url. However, you have to add the slash at the end. Otherwise Django won't work as expected.

Comment: How about `localhost:8000/polls/`? Is it works? You could put your ROOT_URL in here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :) Eventhough the ROOT_URL wasn't the problem, your post has pushed me into the right direction to resolve the issue. Thank you once again.

Comment: @ IlikedCPlusPlus glad to hear you solved your problem.